# Show $0 < x, y \leq c \implies \frac {x+y}{1 + \frac{xy}{c^2}} \leq c.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, contest-math

> Given $0 < x, y \leq c,$ show $\dfrac {x+y}{1 + \frac{xy}{c^2}} \leq c.$
>
> (*Source: Art of Problem Solving*)

My solution is below.  I request verification, suggestions, or feedback  *Note: Other proofs may exist; I request verification and critique of **this** proof.*

**Proof:** It suffices to show that $0 < a, b \leq 1$ implies $\frac {a+b}{ab + 1} \leq 1,$ and then let $a = \frac x c, b = \frac y c$.

Let $\alpha = 1 - a, \beta = 1 - b$.  Then $$\begin{align}
ab + 1 &= (1 - \alpha)(1 - \beta) + 1 \\
&= 1 - \alpha + 1 - \beta + \alpha \beta \\
&= a + b + \alpha \beta \\
&\geq a + b.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Looks fine, that's a very interesting method, never seen that one before

Comment: @DanielGeyfman I was trying to think "Why is this true?".  $a+b$ reminds me of AM, $ab$ of GM, and although $AM \geq GM$, this inequality places a bound on that (in a loose, very brainstormy way...).  From there I said "Well, let's quantify how much lower $a$ and $b$ are and call these $\alpha$ and $\beta$".  Then the proof was immediate, and the rest was just simplifying the algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct but you don't need $\alpha $ and $\beta$ (perhaps you could mentioned that they are nonegative). Simply subtract $ab+1$ and $a+b$:  $$ab+1-a-b = (a-1)(b-1)\geq 0$$

Comment: This certainly shortens the proof.  But wouldn't you agree that the form in the OP provides more insight as to what is going on? We have $ab + 1 \approx a + b$ plus an error term $\alpha \beta$, which is clearly $> 0$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct again.